# Java Heap committed memory is bigger than -Xmx

Tags: java, memory-leaks, heap-memory, jmap, jcmd

I am trying to hunt the memory leak in Java Spring Boot app inside docker container.

Heap size of the app is limited like this:

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -jar /app-0.1.jar -Xms256m -Xmx512m
```

Native memory diff looks like this:

```
 ./jcmd 7 VM.native_memory summary.diff
```

> Native Memory Tracking:
>
> Total: reserved=8295301KB +1728KB, committed=2794537KB +470172KB
>
> ```
>             Java Heap (reserved=6469632KB, committed=2245120KB +466944KB)
>                         (mmap: reserved=6469632KB, committed=2245120KB +466944KB)
>
>                 Class (reserved=1141581KB -9KB, committed=103717KB -9KB)
>                         (classes #16347 -86)
>                         (malloc=13133KB -9KB #23221 -306)
>                         (mmap: reserved=1128448KB, committed=90584KB)
>
>                Thread (reserved=85596KB +999KB, committed=85596KB +999KB)
>                         (thread #84 +1)
>                         (stack: reserved=85220KB +1027KB, committed=85220KB +1027KB)
>                         (malloc=279KB +3KB #498 +6)
>                         (arena=97KB -31 #162 +2)
>
>                  Code (reserved=255078KB +32KB, committed=32454KB +228KB)
>                         (malloc=5478KB +32KB #8900 +80)
>                         (mmap: reserved=249600KB, committed=26976KB +196KB)
>
>                    GC (reserved=249066KB -2KB, committed=233302KB +1302KB)
>                         (malloc=12694KB -2KB #257 -75)
>                         (mmap: reserved=236372KB, committed=220608KB +1304KB)
>
>              Compiler (reserved=227KB +10KB, committed=227KB +10KB)
>                         (malloc=96KB +10KB #807 +15)
>                         (arena=131KB #7)
>
>              Internal (reserved=68022KB +720KB, committed=68022KB +720KB)
>                         (malloc=67990KB +720KB #21374 -287)
>                         (mmap: reserved=32KB, committed=32KB)
>
>                Symbol (reserved=21938KB -11KB, committed=21938KB -11KB)
>                         (malloc=19436KB -11KB #197124 -188)
>                         (arena=2501KB #1)
>
>  Native Memory Tracking (reserved=3962KB -12KB, committed=3962KB -12KB)
>                         (malloc=15KB #178 +1)
>                         (tracking overhead=3947KB -12KB)
>
>           Arena Chunk (reserved=199KB, committed=199KB)
>                         (malloc=199KB)
> ```

After taking the heap dump:

```
./jmap -dump:live,format=b,file=/tmp/dump2.hprof 7
```

The heap `Leak Suspects` report is quite small - 45MB:

[image]

The question:
why is Java Heap committed=2245120KB - almost 2GB? It's not aligned with `-Xmx512m` nor with  heap dump size taken with `jmap`.

Answer (score 1):

The answer is actually simple:

Params `-Xms256m -Xmx512m` were passed in wrong place and therefore ignored by JVM. The correct order of params is like this:

```
java -XX:NativeMemoryTracking=summary -Xms256m -Xmx512m -jar /app-0.1.jar
```

Also, dump is much smaller than `Java Heap committed` because only **live** objects were dumped, due to `-dump:live`. After changing dump command to:

```
./jmap -dump:format=b,file=/tmp/dump2.hprof 7
```

the size of dump is very close to `Java Heap committed`.